# Make sub-links in the left ribbon

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, master-page, links, left-navigation

I am trying to organize my left ribbon so that the links for the web parts are indented after the page containing them.

In this picture I want that "Listes des réunions" is indented under "Réunions", but it just works for the link "Récent" that isn't even a page.

[image: Link is indented]

Link is indented

[image: Link isn't indented]

Link isn't indented

Thank you for your response.

Comment: Is it team site or communication site?

Comment: it's a team site.

Comment: Are you able to see the **Edit** link below left navigation?

Comment: Yes, and I can also move the links, but I can't indent them after a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below steps to create sub-links in left navigation:

1. Go to Site Settings.
2. Select **Quick Launch**.
3. Select **New Navigation Link**.
4. Add URL of "Listes des réunions" under "Type the Web address:" text box.
5. Add "Listes des réunions" under "Type the description:" text box.
6. Select "Réunions" from "Heading" dropdown.
7. Click **OK**.